# Where can I find free Icons?

Tags: icons

I'm looking for websites dedicated to icons (free icons of course).

I'm placing a list of some sites that I know, but I'm looking for others:

- **We love icons** - [link](http://weloveicons.com/)
- **VeryIcon** - [link](http://veryicon.com/)
- **DeviantArt** - [link](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/icons/)
- **FreeIconsDownload** - [link](http://www.freeiconsdownload.com)
- **IconArchive** - [link](http://www.iconarchive.com/)
- **IconFactory** - [link](http://iconfactory.com)

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Should be community wiki

Comment: I really thought icons were used in computer software, maybe my mistake since the question got closed.

Comment: If I had the rep I've vote to reopen this

Answer (score 3):

[Pinvoke.com](http://www.pinvoke.com/) has two quite nice icon sets. [Famfamfam](http://famfamfam.com/lab/icons/) as well.

All licensed unter CC-By.

Answer (score 3):

I *love* [fatcow](http://www.fatcow.com/free-icons/). [Silk](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) and [Tango](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) ain't half bad.

Comment: Commenting because my low rep won't allow me to post more than one link at a time:

Silk:
http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/

and Tango ain't half bad:
http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project

Comment: Inserted the links for you

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/) a few times. It indexes lots of icon sets by keywords, you can limit the search by the size of the icon, and it displays the license for each icon/set (and you can filter out those that aren't allowed for commercial use, if necessary).

Comment: +8524. Iconfinder is amazing. I'm glad they redesigned the home page.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.crazyleafdesign.com/blog/sunday-design-resource-issue-3-500-icons-every-designer-needs/
http://www.visualpharm.com/office_space_icon_set/ (adding a link)

Answer (score 1):

The [Tango Project](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Desktop_Project) has of course a nice variety of different icons.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources I use often:

- [Find Icons](http://findicons.com/--)
- [Professional Icones](http://icones.pro/en/-)
- [Iconspedia](http://www.iconspedia.com/)

Answer (score 0):

http://art.gnome.org/ sorta hard to navigate but there's quite a collection there. GPL licensed.